# How to include a information in xml header when using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a complete noob when it comes to xslt and need some help with the following...

I have written an xslt which outputs what I want except for the header. This is what I want to appear:

```
<etd_ms:thesis xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/ 
                     http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

This is what I get with my transform:

```
<etd_ms:thesis 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/ 
                     http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd">
```

Here is the relevant portion of the transform itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/ 
                                http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
rest of code....
```

How do I accomplish what I want. I though this line would do what I want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/ http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd">
```

Here is an example of the input:

```
<generic_etd>
  <dc.creator>Some Person</dc.creator>
  <dc.date>2006</dc.date>
  <dc.description.abstract>Long lines of text</dc.description.abstract> 
  <dc.description.note>Masters Abstracts</dc.description.note>
  <dc.format>application/pdf</dc.format>
  <dc.format>105 p.</dc.format>
  <dc.format>2.15 MB</dc.format>
  <dc.language>eng</dc.language>
  <dc.publisher>Publisher</dc.publisher>
  <dc.subject>Ecology.</dc.subject>
  <dc.title>My awesome title.</dc.title>
</generic_etd>
```

Added an example of the code [here](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyG/3)

But it isn't doing what I want it to. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: There must be something missing. You get a `xsi` prefix but no `xsi` namespace declaration? What does your source look like?

Comment: You need to include a (minimal) example of your input. Note that the (only) part of the stylesheet that you show us **copies** nodes from the input, including their namespace/s. The namespace declarations in your stylesheet header play no role here.

Comment: Added input file as an example of what I am processing.

Comment: That's good, but the output is NOT what you show us: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyG

Comment: I have updated the example in your link. I didn't get what you were getting at before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest the following as the starting point for your transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/generic_etd">
    <etd_ms:thesis xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/ http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </etd_ms:thesis>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="etd_ms:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<etd_ms:thesis xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/ http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd">
   <etd_ms:dc.creator>Some Person</etd_ms:dc.creator>
   <etd_ms:dc.date>2006</etd_ms:dc.date>
   <etd_ms:dc.description.abstract>Long lines of text</etd_ms:dc.description.abstract>
   <etd_ms:dc.description.note>Masters Abstracts</etd_ms:dc.description.note>
   <etd_ms:dc.format>application/pdf</etd_ms:dc.format>
   <etd_ms:dc.format>105 p.</etd_ms:dc.format>
   <etd_ms:dc.format>2.15 MB</etd_ms:dc.format>
   <etd_ms:dc.language>eng</etd_ms:dc.language>
   <etd_ms:dc.publisher>Publisher</etd_ms:dc.publisher>
   <etd_ms:dc.subject>Ecology.</etd_ms:dc.subject>
   <etd_ms:dc.title>My awesome title.</etd_ms:dc.title>
</etd_ms:thesis>
```

Comment: When I use this with the PHP XSLTProcessor processor it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @user5013 "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem. In any case, I believe this should work with any XSLT processor.